# Exponential growth and decay,and the constant k

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

In the equation $$A=Be^{kt}$$,where $B$ is the initial amount and $t$ is the time taken what is $k$,I know it's a constant of proportionality ,but is it the same as the number of time a certain amount of money gets compounded every year?

For example, if an amount of $\$~500$ is getting compounded four times at the rate of $5~\%$ per year ,here if they ask what is the amount if the money is compounded every instant ,the equation will the somewhat similar to exponential growth equation,is the number 4 here same as k?

Comment: While the equations are similar, I wouldn't recommend thinking that "4 is the same as $k$". Question: What do you mean by "compounded four times at the rate of $5~\%$ per year"? Do you mean that the interest is given four times a year, so that the total yearly interest is $5~\%$ ?

Comment: Yeah,pls bear my english

Comment: The equation $A = Be^{kt}$ is made for the situation where money is compounded "every instant." If the money is compounded $4$ times a year, then a different equation is needed (unless we only want an approximation).

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ok say my imaginary bank compounds every second ,at the rate of 100% every year,it will be somewhat closer to e .here is 31,536,000 seconds same as k?

Comment: @user794763 The number of times compounded is **not** the same as $k$. In the equation $A = Be^{kt}$, $k$ is the yearly compounding rate. For the question you posted, $k = 0.05$. For the question you just commented, $k = 1$.

Comment: @user794763 For your imaginary bank, the amount at time $t$ is very close to the approximation $A = Be^{1 \cdot t}$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann ,is it okay to say that k is the rate at which the amount ((or) whatever) grows with respect to the original amount of substance (ie)B here, in the given time t?

Comment: @user794763 That is a reasonable way to think about it, but your statement is technically incorrect.

Comment: @BenGrossmann  r (or) k ,can i say that it is the rate at which it is compounded continously

Comment: @user794763 That phrasing is also problematic. The clearest way to refer to $r$ or $k$ is as the "nominal annual interest rate."

Answer (score 2):

$k$ is often described as the *[continuously compounding rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Continuous_compounding)* or the *[logarithmic return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Logarithmic)*.

If we took your example of $\$ 500$ compounded four times at the rate of $5\%$ per year and wrote it as $A=500 \times (1.05)^4 \approx 607.75$ then we could write this as $A=Be^{kt}$ where

- $B=500$, the initial amount
- $t=4$, the time in years
- $k=\log_e(1.05)\approx 0.04879$

and get the same result.  The same approach would work for integer $t$, and we could see it as a reasonable approach for non-integer time $t$.

To me in this example $e^k-1 = 0.05$ is the *annual rate* of growth, but some people use that phrase to mean $k$ itself and so it is important that two people communicating are clear about what they are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

As Ben Grossmann also has explained in the comments, in your example, $k$ refers to *the annual rate* (provided $t$ is measured in years). Then your formula can be used to calculate *the annual yield* - the ratio of the total amount at the end of the year to the total amount at the beginning of the year.

Specifically, the rate is

$$r=e^k-1$$

See [Effective interest rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate) for details.